# Algorithm to decrement index and go back no max array length

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This question is just for curiosity.

I know this algorithm to increment an array index and go back to zero without using if:

```
getNextIndex(index,length) : number {
    return ++index % length;
}
```

So, for example, if an array has length 5, when index hits 5 it calculates '5 % 5' and goes back to zero. I can increment again and again without index out of bounds.

Do you guys know a similtar algorithm to **decrement** index without if?

Like this:

```
getPrevIndex(index,length) : number {
    index--;
    if(index < 0) {
        index = length-1;
    }
    return index;
}
```

But without boolean clause: index < 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getPrevIndex(index,length) : number {
    return (index + length - 1) % length;
}
```